# Attack & Taking Damage For 2d Game Using Unity 3d

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Having a little problem. I have made some scripts which are error free, but having trouble trying to initiate the attack animation in sprite factory in Unity 3d to essentially animate when character or enemy is attacking. They both are bone idle. I have attached the necessary rigidbody2d and box colliders on both my main character and enemy but lack any interaction. I have managed to get my run animation active for my character using Sprite Factory (code below as an example)

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using FactorySprite = SpriteFactory.Sprite;
public class Walk : MonoBehaviour {

// you forgot to set name of variable representing your sprite
private FactorySprite sprite;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    sprite = GetComponent<FactorySprite> (); // Edited
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {


            if (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.RightArrow)) {
                    sprite.Play ("Walk"); // heh, remember C# is case sensitive :)
                    Vector3 pos = transform.position;
                    pos.x += Time.deltaTime * 12;
                    transform.position = pos;

            } else if (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.LeftArrow)) {
                    sprite.Play ("Walk0"); // heh, remember C# is case sensitive :)
                    Vector3 pos = transform.position;
                    pos.x += Time.deltaTime * -12;
                    transform.position = pos;
    }
    else{
        sprite.Stop();
    }
}
}
```

Scripts are below [Player Attack]

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;public class PlayerAttack : MonoBehaviour {
public GameObject target;
public float attackTimer;
public float coolDown;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    attackTimer = 0;
    coolDown = 2.0f;
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
    if(attackTimer > 0)
        attackTimer -= Time.deltaTime;

    if(attackTimer < 0)
        attackTimer = 0;

    if(Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.F)) {
        if(attackTimer == 0) {
            Attack();
            attackTimer = coolDown;
        }
    }

}

private void Attack() {
    float distance = Vector3.Distance(target.transform.position, transform.position);

    Vector3 dir = (target.transform.position - transform.position).normalized;

    float direction = Vector3.Dot(dir, transform.forward);

    if(distance < 2.5f) {
        if(direction > 0) {
            EnemyHealth eh = (EnemyHealth)target.GetComponent("EnemyHealth");
            eh.AddjustCurrentHealth(-10);
        }
    }
}
}
```

Player Health:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
public class PlayersHealth : MonoBehaviour {
public int maxHealth = 100;
public int curHealth = 100;

public float healthBarLength;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    healthBarLength = Screen.width / 2;
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
    AddjustCurrentHealth(0);
}

void OnGUI() {
    GUI.Box(new Rect(10, 10, healthBarLength, 20), curHealth + "/" + maxHealth);
}

public void AddjustCurrentHealth(int adj) {
    curHealth += adj;

    if(curHealth < 0)
        curHealth = 0;

    if(curHealth > maxHealth)
        curHealth = maxHealth;

    if(maxHealth < 1)
        maxHealth = 1;

    healthBarLength = (Screen.width / 2) * (curHealth / (float)maxHealth);
}
}
```

Enemy Attack

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
public class EnemyAttack : MonoBehaviour {
public GameObject target;
public float attackTimer;
public float coolDown;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    attackTimer = 0;
    coolDown = 2.0f;
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
    if(attackTimer > 0)
        attackTimer -= Time.deltaTime;

    if(attackTimer < 0)
        attackTimer = 0;

    if(attackTimer == 0) {
        Attack();
        attackTimer = coolDown;
    }
}

private void Attack() {
    float distance = Vector3.Distance(target.transform.position, transform.position);

    Vector3 dir = (target.transform.position - transform.position).normalized;

    float direction = Vector3.Dot(dir, transform.forward);

    if(distance < 2.5f) {
        if(direction > 0) {
            PlayersHealth eh = (PlayersHealth)target.GetComponent("PlayersHealth");
            eh.AddjustCurrentHealth(-10);
        }
    }
}
}
```

Enemy Health

```
Using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
public class EnemyHealth : MonoBehaviour {
public int maxHealth = 100;
public int curHealth = 100;

public float healthBarLength;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    healthBarLength = Screen.width / 2;
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
    AddjustCurrentHealth(0);
}

void OnGUI() {
    GUI.Box(new Rect(10, 40, healthBarLength, 20), curHealth + "/" + maxHealth);
}

public void AddjustCurrentHealth(int adj) {
    curHealth += adj;

    if(curHealth < 0)
        curHealth = 0;

    if(curHealth > maxHealth)
        curHealth = maxHealth;

    if(maxHealth < 1)
        maxHealth = 1;

    healthBarLength = (Screen.width / 2) * (curHealth / (float)maxHealth);
}
}
```

I would love anyones expertise on this because I am on the final stage of the level and this is really taking its toll.

Comment: Why are you calling AddjustCurrentHealth every frame with EnemyHealth's Update method? As long as the only way to modify the health of the EnemyHealth object's maxHealth and curHealth values (meaning you should make them properties with private setters) is through the AddjustCurrentHealth method, you should only need to call it when there is actually an adjustment to make.

Comment: Also, I don't see where exactly in the Attack() methods you're starting their animations. It doesn't seem to be present at all.

Comment: why are you using the "FactorySprite", the unity animator is great to work with 2D, there are a lot of tutorials and well... it's already inside unity....and just like @eshs mentioned, I can not see a call to "sprite.Play()" in your Attack() methods.